# user profile with django

Tags: python, django, class, profile

What would be the steps to create a user profile other than the administrator user please, I am a newbie. I leave the model class of which I want to be a user profile

[image: models]

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = models.OneToOneField(User, ondelete=models.CASCADE)
```

Add this field to the model.

If you are using Django's auth user registration form then, while registering new user in views.py:

```
form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save()
    apoderado = Apoderado()
    apoderado.user = instance
    apoderado.other_fields = form.cleaned_data['other_fields']
    apoderado.save()
```

This will create new user with extra fields. This is a simple trick but, if any error occurs then only half of data will be stored. If you want to go for extra, use Django signals.